# DateTime - ModelState.IsValid Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

here is my View model entry

```
 [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
 public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

and here how it is handeled in View

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DateCreated , new { Value = DateTime.Now })
```

ModelState.IsValid is giving this error for DateCreated field coming from the form:

```
"The value '07/13/2018 10:54:04' is not valid for DateCreated ."
```

The point is the fact that the problems appear "suddenly". It was working a while ago and without changing anything the problem appears.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should take created date from action.

Comment: Check your model binder and culture options. The date format should match with `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format.

Comment: Added 
 `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}")]
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }`

still not working

Comment: The input date format seems follow `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format. Ensure that current model binder matches this definition; if not, custom model binder should be enabled to allow both `dd/MM/yyyy` and `MM/dd/yyyy` input.

Comment: it is so strange since I did not change anything about this part of the code and it started to happen.

Comment: The culture of your server should have matched with desired date format. If `dd/MM/yyyy` works but not otherwise, then you should change current server culture, or create custom model binder to accept both formats regardless of server's culture settings.

Comment: define your date format and culture explicitly in Global.asax

Comment: This is a binding error, not a display error. The only way to avoid it is to *not* pass any localized *strings* when a date is expected. When you pass strings to an action, you should use the ISO8601 format. In Javascript, use `Date.toISOString()` to produce a correct string.

Comment: Since this string is generated by `Html.HiddenFor()`  you should probaly *remove* `DisplayFormat` completely. `DisplayFormat` affects how things are displayed, not parsed. If that doesn't work, change the format string to ISO8601, eg `{0:s}`

Comment: @ilishim btw you didn't post your action's code. How does it try to read the date?

Comment: `public ActionResult DocumentAdd(Document doc){}`
and **DateCreated** is one of the properties of Document class. I am just passing Document object to action.  The way @NoorAllSafaet suggested worked for me. Now I am assigning the DateTime.Now value in the action and removed the html.hiddenfor in my view.